# Disabling Azure Insights sampling does not work

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I am working on a Azure Function in .NET Core 3.1. I have noticed that it does not save all of the desired data into the Azure Insights. To be sure, i tried to run my function on a localhost and added logging not only to the AI, but also, every time that i try to log data into the AI, i also created a text file with the data that i wanted to log to. The quantity of created text files is exactly the same as I've expected, while I've got way less entries in AI logs.

To disable sampling, i tried various configurations of host.json file, the current content of that file is:

```
  "version": "2.0",
  "functionTimeout": "-1",
  "logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "always",
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": false,
        "maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond": 10000,
        "excludedTypes": "Debug,Trace,Warning,Error,Information,Critical"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(Since setting isEnabled to false didn't help, i also tried to set sufficient quantity of max telemetry items per second, but it didn't help, too)

And it didn't worked (neither on my local computer and deployed on Azure); i also tried to disable it by code:

```
namespace MyAzureFunction
{
    public class MyStartup : IWebJobsStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
        {
            var configDescriptor = builder.Services.SingleOrDefault(tc => tc.ServiceType == typeof(TelemetryConfiguration));
            if (configDescriptor?.ImplementationFactory != null)
            {
                var aiOptions = new ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions();
                aiOptions.EnableAdaptiveSampling = false;

                var implFactory = configDescriptor.ImplementationFactory;
                builder.Services.Remove(configDescriptor);
                builder.Services.AddSingleton(provider =>
                {
                    if (implFactory.Invoke(provider) is TelemetryConfiguration config)
                    {
                        var newConfig = TelemetryConfiguration.Active;
                        newConfig.ApplicationIdProvider = config.ApplicationIdProvider;
                        newConfig.InstrumentationKey = config.InstrumentationKey;
                        return newConfig;
                    }
                    return null;
                });

                builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(aiOptions);
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, when i run my function on a localhost, that's what i see in the commandline window:

```
[2022-08-24T13:37:55.249Z] {
[2022-08-24T13:37:55.250Z]   "version": "2.0",
[2022-08-24T13:37:55.252Z]   "functionTimeout": "-1",
[2022-08-24T13:37:55.253Z]   "logging": {
[2022-08-24T13:37:55.254Z]     "fileLoggingMode": "always",
[2022-08-24T13:37:55.255Z]     "logLevel": {
[2022-08-24T13:37:55.257Z]       "default": "Information"
[2022-08-24T13:37:55.258Z]     },
[2022-08-24T13:37:55.259Z]     "applicationInsights": {
[2022-08-24T13:37:55.260Z]       "samplingSettings": {
[2022-08-24T13:37:55.262Z]         "isEnabled": false,
(...)
[2022-08-24T13:37:57.043Z] Initializing Host. OperationId: ...
[2022-08-24T13:37:57.055Z] Host initialization: ConsecutiveErrors=0, StartupCount=1, OperationId=...
[2022-08-24T13:37:57.087Z] ApplicationInsightsLoggerOptions
[2022-08-24T13:37:57.089Z] {
[2022-08-24T13:37:57.089Z]   "SamplingSettings": null,
[2022-08-24T13:37:57.090Z]   "SamplingExcludedTypes": null,
[2022-08-24T13:37:57.091Z]   "SamplingIncludedTypes": null,
[2022-08-24T13:37:57.092Z]   "SnapshotConfiguration": null,
```

As you can see, even though it read the host config with sampling turned off, SamplingSettings are null, but i can't find a way to effectively disable it.

Comment: It's possible the app is sending all telemetry, but the Azure AI resource is itself set to do sampling.  Try checking the sampling rate on the Azure AI resource is 100%.

Comment: @AndrewS Thanks for an advice, but i opened that AI resource in the Azure portal and under a tab "Usage and estimated costs", when i choose "Data sampling", i see that it's set to "All data (100%)".

Comment: Please confirm that sampling is the cause, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling#knowing-whether-sampling-is-in-operation

Comment: Could it be that the logLevel has anything to do with it. What information are you missing? Are you seeing a pattern in the excluded logs?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm having the same problem

Comment: @PeterH unfortunatelly, i did not solve this. I had to move to more urgent tasks. If i'll ever encounter this again and fix it, I'll let you know how.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce your issue. I'm able to get the all the telemetry information in application insights after disabling the sampling.

- Thanks @Andrew S, for your suggestion Check Sampling rate in Azure Application Insights resource is 100%
- Sampling based on the request's Operation ID. Telemetry items associated with a specific operation are either preserved or dropped.

#### The workaround follows

I have used the same **`host.json`** file configuration which you used.

```json
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": false,
        "maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond": 10000,
        "excludedTypes": "Debug,Trace,Warning,Error,Information,Critical"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Disabling sampling in `startup.cs`

```cs
  var aiOptions = new ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions();
  aiOptions.EnableAdaptiveSampling = false;
  builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(aiOptions);
```

The result I have got from both Local and Azure:
Local
[image]

Deployed same function in Azure
**`host.json`**
[image]

log file generated in KUDU
[image]

Result in AI
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The sampling settings do not appear to be setup correctly for the excluded types property.

> Recognized types are: Dependency, Event, Exception, PageView, Request, Trace.

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling#:~:text=subject%20to%20sampling.-,Recognized%20types%20are%3A%20Dependency%2C%20Event%2C%20Exception%2C%20PageView%2C%20Request%2C%20Trace.,-All%20telemetry%20of](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling#:%7E:text=subject%20to%20sampling.-,Recognized%20types%20are%3A%20Dependency%2C%20Event%2C%20Exception%2C%20PageView%2C%20Request%2C%20Trace.,-All%20telemetry%20of)